# Using XPath, how to select uncle/nephew in the same result?

Tags: xml, xpath

Let's assume the following XML:

```xml
<top>
  <head>
    <node address="some value"></node>
    <othernode key="some other value"></othernode>
    <lower>
      <deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
      <evenlower>
        <evendeepernode text="blablabla"></evendeepernode>
      </evenlower>
    </lower>
  </head>
  <head>
    <node address="some value"></node>
    <othernode key="some other value"></othernode>
    <lower>
      <deepnode key="some value">lorem</deepnode>
      <evenlower>
        <evendeepernode text="blablabla"></evendeepernode>
      </evenlower>
    </lower>
  </head>
  <head>
    <node address="some value"></node>
    <othernode key="some other value"></othernode>
    <lower>
      <deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
      <evenlower>
        <evendeepernode text="blablabla"></evendeepernode>
      </evenlower>
    </lower>
  </head>
</top>
```

Then, for each `head`, I would like to select both `node`, and `deepnode` that contains the word "ipsum".
I only care about these 2 nodes, meaning I **do not** want the `evendeepernode`s or `othernode`s to also be printed.

Desired result:

```xml
<results>
  <result>
    <node address="some value"></node>
    <lower>
      <deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
    </lower>
  </result>
  <result>
    <node address="some value"></node>
    <lower>
      <deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
    </lower>
  </result>
</results>
```

Can this be done? :-)

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

`'/top/*[self::node and self::lower/deepnode[contains(@key="some value",'ipsum')]]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this be done?

No, not the way you envision it.

XPath is a *selection language*. It can only select what's there. For example this

```
//node[following-sibling::*[contains(.//deepnode, 'ipsum')]]
```

will select the two matching `<node>` elements:

```
<node key="some value"></node>

<node key="some value"></node>
```

And this

```
//deepnode[contains(., 'ipsum')]
```

will select two matching `<deepnode>` elements

```
<deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>

<deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
```

You could even combine those two expressions with the union operator `(expr1|expr2)`, which would return four nodes:

```
<node key="some value"></node>

<deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>

<node key="some value"></node>

<deepnode key="some value">lorem ipsum dolor</deepnode>
```

But it this still does not look anything like the output document you suggest. XPath cannot build documents. It can give you lists of nodes that match certain criteria.

What you want is to transform the input XML into something else. This can be done with e.g. XSLT or XQuery, or through manual DOM building in any host programming language that supports XML.

Answer (score 1):

To select (only to select) your nodes, assuming `//head` is your context node, you can use :

```
.//*[name()="deepnode" and string(@key)='some value' and contains(.,"ipsum") or name()="node" and string(@key)='some value' and following::deepnode[1][contains(.,"ipsum")]]
```

or shorter :

```
.//*[position()=1 and parent::head and following::deepnode[1][@key="some value" and contains(.,"ipsum")] or contains(text(),"ipsum")]
```

Output : 4 nodes.

Comment: What's the point of doing `//*[name()="..."]`? (I know what it does, I don't know why you're using that.)

Comment: You mean the first expression ? Since I don't use "|" to write the XPath, I can't write it in another way with the conditions expected (2 types of elements with specific attributes and 1 contain condition). I'm open for suggestions though.

Comment: I guess your way of constructing the expressions is very long-winded, also the lack of parentheses is confusing - I did not even scroll all the way to the end so I missed the `or` in there. So the question changes to: Why not use the `|`? This would make the expression simpler.

Comment: Yes, the expression could be shorter  with "|" operator (and probably faster). I'm also in favor of the shortest, the simplest, the fastest. But I don't use `|` very often. Consider it like a challenge to write the expression without it.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```
//*[@key="some value" and contains(.,"ipsum")]
```

In your example, the 'node' and 'deepnode' have the same key so you can check the key is right and then check it contains "ipsum".

Comment: Apologies, node contains a different 'key name' in my real example. I've changed this in the original question now. How would I get the same result when 'node' has 'address' instead of 'key'?

Comment: You can find nodes by attribute by putting [@attribute="example"] so ```//node[@address="example]``` or ```//node[contains(@address,"example")]```